# prolog : How to check if the first character is uppercase

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I would like to know how to check if the first character of string is a uppercase in prolog .

Answer (score 2):

`code_type/2`, `char_type/2` are [your friends](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chartype):

```erlang
?- String='Hello world',get_string_code(1,String,First),code_type(First,upper).
String = 'Hello world',
First = 72.

?- String="Hello world",get_string_code(1,String,First),code_type(First,upper).
String = "Hello world",
First = 72.

?- String=`Hello world`,get_string_code(1,String,First),code_type(First,upper).
String = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114|...],
First = 72.
```

These 3 examples show different kinds of strings, and be aware last one is available *only* starting from SWI-Prolog v.7, where it replaces double quoted literals, that were, historically, lists of codes.